# What is the correct verb for "driving" a boat?

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you describe driving a boat? Is is correct to say

- drive a boat
- steer a boat
- sail a boat?

Comment: what kind of boat are we talking about?  certainly one would not sail a boat that lacks a sail.  or do you want a word that fits for all boats?

Comment: Ideally all boats

Answer (score 28):

The common term is "***piloting***".

Per Google definition:

> ***pilot*** (gerund or present participle: ***piloting***): act as a pilot of (an aircraft or **ship**).
>
> synonyms: ***navigate***, *guide*, *maneuver*, *steer*, *control*, *direct*, ***captain***, *shepherd*

Per the Oxford English Dictionary (OED):

> ***[pilot](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/143951?rskey=omphII&result=2%23eid)***: To conduct or convey (a person) in a ship or boat; **to direct the course of (a vessel)**, esp. through difficult or dangerous waters; to guide or steer. Also occas. intr.: to perform the role of pilot on a vessel.

Per the SeaTalk Nautical Dictionary:

> ***[pilot](http://www.seatalk.info/cgi-bin/nautical-marine-sailing-dictionary/db.cgi?db=db&uid=default&FirstLetter=p&sb=Term&view_records=View%20Records&nh=3)***: **to operate a vessel**, meaning to steer safely to a destination
>
> See Also: *navigate*

Comment: This is mainly used in situations where a pilot is on board the ship (pilot: A person with expert local knowledge qualified to take charge of a ship entering or leaving a harbour.) (as the reference you cite also says) [ [ODO, which you call 'Google'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pilot) ]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The word has more than one definition. The *local expert guiding a vessel to harbor through dangerous waters* is one, but another is simply *to operate or direct a vessel*. See my updated answer with citations from both the OED (real one, not ODO) and the SeaTalk Nautical Dictionary. They both record this sense as well as yours. Also I called it "Google definition" because I literally typed *[define pilot]* into the Google search box and quoted the result, which was not attributed to ODO or anyone else.

Comment: I'd say the _common term_ is 'sailing' (used double-metonymically: quite possibly no sails, and one doesn't 'cruise' a car but cruises in a car).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Seems like a fine answer to me. The issue is that *everyone in the crew* is "sailing" the vessel, not just the master, captain, navigator, or pilot. And while I can say I *sailed* to Grand Cay, I cannot claim I was directing the boat that got me there: I was not *piloting* or *navigating* it.

Comment: @Dn Bron You're not taking account of the 'to manoeuvre or navigate a vessel' sense for 'sail' given above. And as for 'the common term', look at Google hits for 'he sailed his ship' vs 'he piloted his ship'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Rather than quibble with me about *sail* under an answer which makes no mention of that word, why not add an answer which does?

Comment: I've close-voted as the OP shows no signs of personal research. And it's not your 'piloting' answer that I'm saying is incorrect, it's your 'The common term is ...'. Have you compared the hits for 'he sailed his ship' versus 'he piloted his ship'? Checked Ngrams?

Comment: Well, the OP did offer several suggestions of his own, at least. Can't say that about every SWR. Personally,  I hold SWRs involving specialized argot or the technical language of some domain to a different standard than general vocabulary questions. At the very least, they're fun to research. But if you believe the question is inadequate and have voted to close it, all well and good. You've done your duty, and so there is no reason to spend more time on it (especially not caviling at the answers the rest of us have put time & effort into supplying).

Comment: @DanBron: I agree, but the question is a duplicate.

Comment: It's academic; the question is a duplicate. In the original, the more usual modern usage of 'pilot' is mentioned, and the fact that a 'common term' is not available is stated.

Comment: @jxh Voting to close as a dupe is legit, IMO.

Comment: Voting to close as a dupe is 'doing your duty'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I need more upvotes before I can do my duty :-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth if you believe that, I recommend you upvote and possibly answer (in the affirmative), [this recent Meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/6896/55623). I tend to recuse myself from closevoting on questions I've already answered, or answering questions I closevoted.

Comment: I have taken your advice (inasmuch as looking at the topic and upvoting). Have you found an authority backing your claim 'the common term is _piloting_'? This is not so according to my impressions (as valid as yours), nor, it would appear, according to raw Google data and Ngrams. OED is a historical dictionary, and STND a nautical glossary. AHDEL, Collins, M-W etc define the verb _pilot_ [nautical] in terms of the noun, with the sense _A person with expert local knowledge qualified to take charge of a ship entering or leaving a harbour_ being ranked as more common than the more general one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I offered a citation in the original version of my answer, and at your prompting further substantiated with references to not only the what is and has been considered the most authoritative dictionary of the English language for the last century, but also a specialized lexicon dedicated to the domain in question. They both record the definition of *pilot* as I have use it (as does the original citation, still). Dictionaries and glossaries reflect how language is used; this definition of pilot is recorded in those reference works because people use it this way.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In sum: the answer is corroborated to my satisfaction, and I will make no more edits, nor add anymore references to authorities, nor engage in any more dialog about the applicability of the word. I will let the voters make their own determination.

Comment: So, does this mean that you can say "We will rent a boat to pilot along the coastline"?

Answer (score 11):

It depends on the boat. You may be **coxing**, if you are sitting in the back of a rowing boat. ([example from Trinity College Cambridge](http://www.firstandthird.org/frames/rowing/coxjob.shtml))

If you are on a sailing boat, then you are, well, **sailing** the boat. But if you have a crew, (and you are potentially telling someone else to turn the wheel or move the tiller) then you are **skippering** or **captaining**.

If you are in a motorboat, to say that you are **driving** it is not inappropriate [according to the UK government](https://www.gov.uk/owning-a-boat/safety-on-inland-waterways).

As the boat gets bigger, you may find that you are **steering** it.

And if you are a water rat, of course, then you are just messing about in boats!

Comment: In other words, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Buoyancy floats my boat!

Comment: In this collection, you are missing ***paddling***, and the more obvious ***rowing***.

Answer (score 8):

You may use ["helm"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/helm).

> Steer (a boat or ship):
>   he helmed a sailing vessel

Perhaps for more informal use there is ["boating"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boating).

> the leisurely activity of travelling by boat, or the recreational use of a boat

Answer (score 2):

I believe *pilot* is the word you want, but as an alternative not yet mentioned, you can use ***skipper***. Its relevance would be on the occasion there is minimal (or no) crew, and where the helmsman and captain are one and the same (a case of [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy)).

> : to be the captain of (a ship or boat)
>   ...
>   *The boat was **skippered** by a skilled veteran sailor.*
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skipper)</sub>

As an example, the [*Manhattan Yacht Club*](https://myc.org/cruising/skipper/) explains how to earn skipper privileges:

> Any member, 18 years or older, can apply for Skipper Privileges if he or she believes they:
>   1) ***can safely skipper a boat in the harbor***
>   2) understand the local sailing conditions (including topography, currents, wind patterns, etc.)
>   3) understand how the club operates (including rules, reservations, responsibilities, etc.).